# Trouble changing to has_many through from has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many-through

I've done about a billion searches and tried a number of things here but I'm still getting errors. I've recently changed to a has many through via a model called joinable(maybe thats the problem) and I can't seem to get things working straight. Part of me thinks it something small as I get the idea of it all but I'm not sure I've done it correctly. I'm also using devise.

Here is what I think are all the relevant portions

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter
  has_many :joinables
  has_many :pits, through: :joinables
  has_many :comments
  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?


class Pit < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :topic, :author, :summary, presence: true
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_votable
  has_many :comments
  has_many :joinables
  has_many :users, through: :joinables
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

I created a separate table called "joinable" and now I'm stuck figuring out how to populate it. I can create a user, but can't create a pit. Do I need to revamp my controllers or is their something small I may be missing? I get the idea but some of the little details are fuzzy based on all that I've read so far. I even tried a HABTM with a join table called Pit_Users.

I'm currently getting "Could not find table 'joinables"

coming from here in my controller

```
def create
@pit = current_user.pits.create(pit_params)
```

recent migration

```
class Joinable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :joinable do |t|
      t.integer :pit_id, :user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
end
```

I've tried a number of combinations all with similar errors. Many of the tutorials/guides are good with the basics but then seem to be leaving out a few details. That or I'm just missing them. Anyways. Would love it if someone more knowledgeable could point out what are probably obvious mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: In the migration file, it should be `class Joinables < ...` and `create_table :joinables do |t|`.

Comment: And it should be `t.integer :pit_id` and on a separate line `t.integer :user_id`

Comment: This seems accurate as it was looking for that table. I'll see what works thanks.

Comment: @roob So I'm pretty sure I created it correctly(did as described above) but I'm now getting an error in my view undefined method `user' for #<Pit:0x000001070da748>. Do I need to change my controller and/or Strong params?

Comment: I've posted the above as an answer, together with a way to verify if the association is working properly. If the association is working correctly, I'll suggest treating the view error as a separate question.

Comment: Thats fine. I'll see what works. I have no issues with separating the questions I just don't want people to get upset if my questions are too close in nature as I've been criticized for that in that past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the migration file, it should be:

```
class Joinables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :joinables do |t|
    t.integer :pit_id  
    t.integer :user_id
  end
end
```

And in the app/models/joinable.rb, there should be:

```
class Joinable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :pit
end
```

You can verify if it is working at the Rails console. Try this to get a Pit record with the association:

```
user_1 = User.create( ... )
pit_1  = user_1.pits.create!( ... )
pit_1.users.first  # should give you user as user_1
```

Comment: So it worked. I was able to create both through the rails console. Thanks. I think I may take your suggestion and post the secondary issue as another question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to run `rails generator for model`

Run from console

`rails generate model Joinable pit:references user:references`

And delete your migration file for

```
class Joinable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :joinable do |t|
      t.integer :pit_id, :user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
end
```

After running `rails generator` you will get `model` named `Joinable` that is required for relations when using `through` and it will create appropriate migration for you.